# Change the leaflet hold touch timing

Tags: javascript, google-maps, ionic-framework, leaflet

I'm using Leaflet for a mobile app developed with Ionic. I currently have a function to search for certain items near a location specified when you make a single click on the map

```
$rootScope.map.on('click', function(e) {
        if (APP_STATUS == ACTION_SEARCH) {
            positionClick = e.latlng;
            $scope.positionSearchClose = positionClick;
            $scope.userPosition.setLatLng(positionClick);
            $scope.popupSearchRoutesClosed = $ionicPopup.show({
                template: $scope.getTemplate(),
                title: 'Buscando rutas',
                scope: $scope,
            });
            $scope.getRoutesClose(positionClick, ACTION_SEARCH);
        }
    });
    $scope.addButtons();
```

I want to change this so that the search happens when the user holds the touch for a brief time. I changed the 'click' parameter to 'contextmenu' and I achieved what I was looking for, but I found out that the hold timing was too long. Despite the leaflet doc description of the ContextMenu event being "Also fired on mobile when the user holds a single touch for a second (also called long press)." it feels like that "second" is an eternity.

Is there a way to make it so the function above only triggers when the user holds the touch, but specifying the amount of time of the hold?

Answer (score 1):

it maybe long time. But i've been searching for this for few hours. i found the solution, which may help anyone who comes here.

In leaflet, touch tap delay declared as 1000ms in a settimeout function. And they can be edited.
In leaflet.js find the below code :

```
// simulate long hold but setting a timeout
this._holdTimeout = setTimeout(bind(function () {
    if (this._isTapValid()) {
        this._fireClick = false;
        this._onUp();
        this._simulateEvent('contextmenu', first);
    }
}, this), 1000);
```

now the 1000(1 second) declared here is the timer, you can change the 1000 to whatever you like...like 300 or 500.

if you want to change touch hold(tap) timer dynamically,
create a variable in the leaflet.js beginning

```
var contextMenuTime = 1000;
```

and manually apply the variable in js the function

```
    ...
    this._simulateEvent('contextmenu', first);
    }
}, this), contextMenuTime);
```

now you can control the tap delay by changing the variable value.